# How to set table border-spacing in tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How can I set a table-border spacing in tailwind? below is the css code
   `border-spacing: 0 15px;`

Comment: here  is the reference https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-collapse

Comment: You should show your code if you are facing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no default border-spacing classes generated by default. But you can create for your own.

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities, matchUtilities, theme }) {
      // add default utilies for border-spacing
      addUtilities({
        '.border-spacing-2': {
          'border-spacing': '0.5rem',
        },
        '.border-spacing-4': {
          'border-spacing': '1rem',
        },
      })

      // add dynamic match for arbitrary values, like border-spacing-[50px]
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'border-spacing': (value) => ({
            'border-spacing': value,
          }),
        },
        { values: theme('borderSpacing') }
      )
    }),
  ],
}
```

Then you can use `border-spacing` classes. Like;

`border-spacing-2`

`border-spacing-[50px]`

`border-spacing-[20px_10px]`

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/spLkekLEp3)

**P.S.** You have to use `border-separate` class on table. Because tailwind uses `border-collapse` by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default class for table border spacing in tailwind css.
while you can create it with padding class, or use ***Cellspacing*** and ***Cellpadding*** attributes of table tag.